# how to do a kernel bisection

Tags: kernel, 15.04, debugging

I posted a bug on luanchpad a few days back (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1452166). I have been told to do a kernel bisection from 3.16 to 3.19.
Can someone give me a simple step by step guide on how to do this? The wiki page on kernel bisection was confusing.

Answer (score 1):

It is not quite easy to do if you do not know how to build kernels. First of all you install all kernel releases one by one and find out on which release the problem appears. It is not too hard. But then you look at kernel related commits between these releases and look for a specific commit, which causes the issue. This part is the hardest one.